# How to log data changed in sql server tables. Which approach is better

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

Just wanted to know about logging data modification.

I have seen to ways of tracking data change (DML).

1. Using Triggers
2. Keeping columns in same table for Added Date, Added By, Modified Date, Modified By.

Using approach (1), I can write triggers for Insert/Delete/Update on each table to log changes and hence can apply foreign key relationship and other constraints like unique key constraints on all the tables as per requirement.

But I didn't understand how it is possible to apply various constrains using approach (2).
Since I have to make composite unique key and have to consider many more columns.

Is there any design issues in database tables. What is the suggested way for approach (2) to log data.

Which approach is better.

Also I have come to know from some of my colleagues that triggers do no fire on bulk insert queries is it true?

Comment: Good question, I've seen/used both approaches and none of them seemed right, I think that rdbms should provide some built-in functionality.

Comment: In Sql Server 2008, a new feature has been introduced i.e. **CDC "change data capture"** that provides the same functionality. But I am concerned for previous versions.

Comment: CDC tells you what changed (including actual data), Change tracking tells you just what rows have changed, but neither tells you who did it. Audit may be your only built-in feature to avoid triggers, but it requires Enterprise. For your 2. if you don't use triggers how do you capture info for ad hoc updates?

Comment: By default triggers will be ignored during BULK INSERT, but there is a FIRE_TRIGGERS option. Doing so of course negates most of the benefits of using bulk insert anyway, especially if your trigger is inefficient.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. I got 2 points from you...Bulk Insert...I was unknown second abt CDC...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand:For approach(2), What I have seen in my previ org..that every table where data was being captured also contains 3 columns Added Date, Modified Date and Row Status...When the row is inserted RowStatus is set to 1. When updated a replicate entry is made into the same table with RowStatus 2 and original row with row status as 1.. But I didn't like this approach..which seems to me as performance ban.

Comment: So you keep a row for every change for all of time? This does not sound optimal at all. I'd rather archive the history elsewhere than pollute the primary table.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: That's exactly I too observed. I asked the same question on Sql Authority http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/24/sql-server-disadvantages-problems-of-triggers/ asking for what database structure other follows to handle this thing

Answer (score 2):

The solution I like best for this is to require (using security features, if possible) all application data access (or at least all CRUD operations) to go through stored procedures, and to have the SPs manage change tracking and auditing.

The problem with triggers is that they don't scale well; they can impose significant performance hits by turning what could be batched inserts or updates into many single-row operations.

As to whether to keep the changes in-row or in another table, my preference is to use another table. That way, I can also have a history of actual changes when needed, rather than just who-and-when. Keeping the source table narrow can also help with query/read performance.

You can also apply partitioning to the audit tables, which will make them easy to age off / drop when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a big one: **[Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)**. Sql Server Enterprise Edition has this feature built in already.

Comment: Thank you. Only issue that we would be changing our database server depending upon customer. So we are trying to have least possible dependency on database server. But thank you for bringing this point.